# Search through CSV file before responding in PHP

Tags: php, ajax, csv

I'm trying to make a promotional code validator via php, by reading from a CSV file. Here's the code for my validator, while 'test.csv' is my csv file :

```
<?php
// if data are received via POST, with index of 'test'
if (isset($_POST['test'])) {
    $file  = fopen('test.csv', 'r');
    $coupon = array($_POST['test']); 
    $coupondef = $_POST['test'];             // get data
    $coupon = array_map('preg_quote', $coupon);
    $regex = '/'.implode('|', $coupon).'/i';
    while (($line = fgetcsv($file)) !== FALSE) {  
    list($promocode, $amount) = $line;

    if(preg_match($regex, $promocode)) {
        echo "Coupon: '<i>".$coupondef."</i> is valid, with ".$amount."% of discount";
        $promocodevalid = 1;
        break;
    } else {
        echo "Coupon: '<i>".$coupondef."</i> is invalid.";
        $promocodevalid = 0;}
}
}
?>
```

Here's my HTML code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="ro">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-2" />
<title>Example Ajax POST</title>

<script type="text/javascript"><!--
function get_XmlHttp() {
  var xmlHttp = null;

  if(window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
  else if(window.ActiveXObject) {   
    xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }

  return xmlHttp;
}

function ajaxrequest(php_file, tagID) {
  var request =  get_XmlHttp();

  var  the_data = 'test='+document.getElementById('txt2').value;

  request.open("POST", php_file, true);

  request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  request.send(the_data);
  request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (request.readyState == 4) {
      document.getElementById(tagID).innerHTML = request.responseText;
    }
  }
}
--></script>
</head>
<body>

<h3 style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="ajaxrequest('couponcheck.php', 'context')"><u>Click</u></h3>
<input type="text" id="txt2" value=""></div>
<div id="context">Here will be displayed the response from the php script.</div>

</body>
</html>
```

The CSV file comes with 2 column in each row - first one is the coupon code while the second one is discount amount. If this processor succeeded in searching the inputted code, it will return the discounted amount and a line of word back to the original file (a html with javascript ajax sender/receiver). If the code couldn't be found, it will send invalid message back to the page.

The problem is, since there are more than 100 lines in my csv file, 100 lines of invalid message will be posted to my receiver page. (or for an amount of lines before it successfully found the code) How am I suppose to let it search through the csv before sending back response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do is not echo if the line is invalid. Just echo if it is valid, in case there is none valid ($promocodevalid = false;) then you can echo the error. Here you go:

```
<?php
    // if data are received via POST, with index of 'test'
    if (isset($_POST['test'])) {
        $promocodevalid = false;
        $file  = fopen('test.csv', 'r');
        $coupon = array($_POST['test']); 
        $coupondef = $_POST['test'];             // get data
        $coupon = array_map('preg_quote', $coupon);
        $regex = '/'.implode('|', $coupon).'/i';
        while (($line = fgetcsv($file)) !== FALSE) {  
           list($promocode, $amount) = $line;

           if(preg_match($regex, $promocode)) {
               echo "Coupon: '<i>".$coupondef."</i> is valid, with ".$amount."% of discount";
               $promocodevalid = true;
               break;
           }
        }
       if(!$promocodevalid) {
           echo "Coupon: '<i>".$coupondef."</i> is invalid.";
       }
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Remember to accept the answer that helped you. This is how the site works. Other people if they have the same question will see what answer helped you and use the same solution.

Comment: Accepted. :D Sorry for the delay.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are calling this php script with Ajax you should just return immediately when you have made a match:

```
<?php
// if data are received via POST, with index of 'test'
if (isset($_POST['test'])) {
    $file  = fopen('test.csv', 'r');
    $coupon = array($_POST['test']); 
    $coupondef = $_POST['test'];             // get data
    $coupon = array_map('preg_quote', $coupon);
    $regex = '/'.implode('|', $coupon).'/i';
    while (($line = fgetcsv($file)) !== FALSE) {  
    list($promocode, $amount) = $line;

    if(preg_match($regex, $promocode)) {
        echo "Coupon: '<i>".$coupondef."</i> is valid, with ".$amount."% of discount";
        exit; // match made, stop the php file now
    } 
}
// if you get here you know there was no match
 echo "Coupon: '<i>".$coupondef."</i> is invalid.";
?>
```

Otherwise, if you reach the terminal condition on your loop you know there was no match (because the script was not killed) so just wait until then to output an "invalid" message.