# Search CSV file and then Return specific rows from CSV file using PHP?

Tags: php, csv

I know this question has been asked before but my problem is different because I need to return the specific rows after a search.

Basically, this is the scenario:

I need to search a CSV file for a specific word/string in the `name` column and then IF the word/string is found I need to get the `row[4]` and `row[5]` and print them in the PHP.

The CSV looks like this:

```
"id","ident","type","name","latitude_deg","longitude_deg","elevation_ft"
6523,"00A","heliport","Heliport",40.07080078125,-74.93360137939453,11,
```

So basically, I need to search by `name` and if found, return the `latitude_deg`,`longitude_deg`.

This is what I have so far... However, this searches the ENTIRE CSV file which makes it slightly slower and it only returns whether the CSV file contains the string/word or not...

```
$search      = "Heliport";
$lines       = file('myCsv.csv');
$line_number = false;

while (list($key, $line) = each($lines) and !$line_number) {
   $line_number = (strpos($line, $search) !== FALSE);
}

if($line_number){
    echo "Results found for " .$search
} else {
    echo "No results found for $search";
}
```

Could someone please advice on this issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Search through CSV file before responding in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14064018/search-through-csv-file-before-responding-in-php)

Answer (score 1):

[`fgetcsv`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) is a good tool for this, it reads a CSV line and breaks it into an array.

```
$search = 'Heliport';
if (($fp = fopen("myCsv.csv", "r")) !== false) {
    while (($row = fgetcsv($fp)) !== false) {
        if($row[3] === $search) {
            echo 'Found ' . $row[3] . ': ' . $row[4] . ', ' . $row[5] . "\n";
        }
    }
    fclose($fp);
}
```